# Delete all the rows from table A under each Name who's ID is less then highest ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create Table A
(
 ID Int,
 Name Varchar(10)
)

Insert Into A Values(1,'A'),
                    (1,'B'),
                    (2,'A'),
                    (3,'A'),
                    (3,'C'),
                    (2,'B'),
                    (2,'C'),
                    (1,'C'),
                    (4,'C'),
                    (4,'B')
SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY NAME,ID
```

Result:

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   A
3   A
1   B
2   B
4   B
1   C
2   C
3   C
4   C
```

If I run this below query:

```
;WITH CTETEST
AS
(
SELECT MAX(ID)[MAXID],Name FROM A GROUP BY NAME
)


SELECT  max([MAXID])[ID],A.Name FROM CTETEST 
 join A
 on A.ID=CTETEST.MAXID
  GROUP BY A.NAME
```

Result:

```
ID  Name
3   A
4   B
4   C
```

I want this above result set in the main base table and delete rest which is less then the highest ID under each Name category. Please suggest me some query.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MS SQLServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an updatable CTE in SQL Server:

```
with todelete as (
      select a.*, max(id) over (partition by name) as maxid
      from a
     )
delete todelete from todelete
     where id < maxid;
```

In almost any database, you can use:

```
delete a
    where id < (select max(id) from a a2 where a2.name = a.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `delete` by `CTE`, make row number by Name `order by ID desc` in `CTE`.

Then only keep `rn = 1` row datas.

```
;with cte as(
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID desc) rn FROM A
)
delete cte
where rn > 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52009c337032a9c64f7a9add1d0f1b1e)

Comment: @PiyushaMohanty Glad to help You can upvote if that help you :)